# Getting error while taking screenshots only for failed test cases using listeners

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng, event-listener

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MKMF.png)

above attached is the test class.. which is getting failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkVFm.png)
This is a utility class for Listener

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS1sp.png)
This is a utility to take Screenshots

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvuXe.png)
This is BaseClass utility. which i have created to provide complete WebDriver Methods to Listeners class.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHkj2.png)
This is the result (console) which is showing after runnig the test.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLCS5.png)

Tests are neither getting failed nor getting passed.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could include the code as text in your question.  Also include the error/exception you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LoginPageTest class, comment the line 'WebDriver driver;' and try, because you are extending the driver instance from BaseClass.